# Missing mathematical characters with fontspec

Tags: math-mode, xetex

When I compiled my document with `xelatex`, the integration symbol does not appear in the desired font (Iwona), and the capital delta does not appear at all. How can I fix this?

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use 3 different fonts, one for French (LinLibertine), one for mathematics (Iwona), and one for chemistry (AntykwaTorunska, mathematical environment with the mono family).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LinLibertine}[Path=/Users/Enfants/Downloads/libertine/,
                            UprightFont=*-Regular,
                            BoldFont=*-Bold,ItalicFont=*-Italic,
                            BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic]
\setmonofont{AntykwaTorunska}[Path=/Users/Enfants/Downloads/antt/,
                                UprightFont=*-Regular,
                                BoldFont=*-Bold,ItalicFont=*-Italic,
                                BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic]
\setsansfont{Iwona}[Path=/Users/Enfants/Downloads/iwona/,
                    UprightFont=*-Regular,
                    BoldFont=*-Bold,ItalicFont=*-Italic,
                    BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic]

\begin{document}

Bonjour. Voici du français.\\

$\mathsf{\displaystyle\int_{\Delta=1}^{n}3\Delta+5}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Welcome to TeX StackExchange! Because you want to use mathematical symbols, have you tried looking into [`mathspec`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/xetex/latex/mathspec/mathspec.pdf)?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know mathspec, I'll look into it.

Comment: If you’re going to keep copies around of specific versions of fonts that are in the TeX distribution, I’d suggest putting them in a `./fonts` subdirectory. This document will break as soon as you compile it on a different box.

Comment: An alternative to `mathspec` is `unicode-math` with `\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}`, or just `fontsetup` with an appropriate option.

Comment: Libertinus Math does not appear to feature a sans-serif `\Delta` glyph.

Comment: @Mico I don't think that unicode has code points for sans serif math greek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to suggest that you employ the `unicode-math` package and set `Libertinus Math` as the math font. I further suggest `\mathsf`, *not* `\symsf`, to switch to math/sans serif while employing "Iwona". And, use `\mathnormal` or `\symsf` to access any missing glyphs -- such as `\Delta`.

This approach also works for `\texttt{abcd}` and `$\mathtt{abcd}$`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setsansfont{Iwona}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmonofont{Antykwa Torunska}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\newcommand\qbf{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.}

\begin{document}
\qbf

\textsf{\qbf}

\texttt{\qbf}

\textsf{3i + 5}, $\mathsf{3i+5}$

\[
\int_{\Delta=1}^{n} 3i+5 \quad 
\mathsf{\int_{\mathnormal{\Delta}=1}^{n} 3i+5}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this solution.

Comment: Perfect, it works very well. Thanks a lot for the tip ;)